# input containing leading zeroes

Tags: c++

In c++ will their be any error if we input an integer containing leading zereos.

for eg:

```
 int a;
 cin>>a;
```

we give an input 00 or 01.

or inputing with the help of string for this is a better idea.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty in trying it.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the leading zeroes?

Comment: i tried and it seems therir is no error, but just wanted to check

Comment: @user315052 no we dont wat tp preserve zeroes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers (or floats for that matter) do not have leading zeroes. If you want to keep the leading zeroes then you have to read the input as a string instead, and convert it to number when needed. Or you can use formatting to add leading zeroes when printing results.

Comment: what about octal or hex literals?

Comment: but if we input 0001 or 0022 will it keep 1 and 22

Comment: @juanchopanza No and no, only actual number is stored in an integer or float. There is no concept of "leading zeroes" in the binary data that is stored in memory.

Comment: You're right. I thought the string conversion functions could use the leading `0` or `0x` from a string representation of a number to infer the base, but I see it isn't the case.

Answer (score 3):

> In c++ will their be any error if we input an integer containing leading zereos.

You might not get what you expect, depending on the settings of the input stream's format flags. The default is to expect user input to always be in decimal. Leading zeros have no effect. What if we turn that off by calling `std::cin.unsetf()`?

```
int main () {
  int i;
  std::cin.unsetf (std::ios::dec);
  while (std::cin >> ii) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
}
```

The output will be 25 if you enter 25, but if you enter 025 the output is 21. That's because C++ now interprets a leading zero on input to mean the number that follows is in octal (or in hexadecimal in the case of a leading 0x or leading 0X).

Answer (score -1):

Leading Zeros will be trimmed off. It wont be stored in the memory.

Comment: They are stored in the memory, because `int` is a fixed size type.