# getline truncating first character

Tags: c++

I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765802/getline-ignores-first-character-of-string-input), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006401/getline-ignoring-first-character-of-input), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092356/getline-skipping-first-input-character-c).  I am not using cin.ignore().  I have two problems with this code, but will limit this to one.  The unsigned int int long "sID" should contain "020961797" but only contains "20961797."

```
bool GPA::importStudents(string mapFileName, string setFileName)
{
long long int sID;
string sName;
string sAddress;
string sPhone;
stringstream ss;

string line;
int mline_count = 0;
int sline_count = 0;
double x;
int y;
ifstream map_file;
ifstream set_file;
map_file.open(mapFileName);
set_file.open(setFileName);

    if (map_file.is_open()){
    for (int i = 0; i < mline_count/4; i++){
        getline(map_file, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> sID;

        getline(map_file, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> sName;

        getline(map_file, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> sAddress;

        getline(map_file, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> sPhone;

        StudentInterface * SI = new Student(sID, sName, sAddress, sPhone);
        my_map.insert(std::pair<unsigned long long int, StudentInterface*>(sID, SI));

        //my_map.emplace(Student(sID, sName, sAddress, sPhone));
    }
}
}
```

Here is the first section of the file from which it should be reading data:

> 020961797
>
> Joshua Cooper
>
> 0509 McCrooke Avenue, Columbus, California 52826
>
> 552-534-8671

Comment: Have you had a look at [input containing leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220129/input-containing-leading-zeroes) ?

Comment: You will have to use strings for this number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sID actually contains `1001111111101101000000101b`, as it has a numerical representation. Printed with the default format, it indeed renders as `20961797`. You can force a leading `0` to get `020961797` if you want by means of the manipulators `setw(9)` and `setfill(' ')`.

Unless you must perform arithmetic on that field value, it is probably more appropriate to handle it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an `int` to store leading zero's you will have to store the sID as a `string` and then convert it any time necessary for it to be a number. Arguably an ID is an identifier rather than a number and you shouldn't actually need to do any mathematical operations with it so a `string` would be an ideal solution

```
string sID = "020961797";

//For some reason you need the ID as a number
int idToInt = atoi(sID.c_str());
```

Please be aware that the int will not hold the leading zero when you convert it though

Answer (score 0):

Numerical types hold numbers, not representations of numbers. "Ten", "10", "010", "the number of fingers I have", and "IIIIIIIIII" are all different representations of the same number. If you want to hold characters, use a string.